# check box value display in results page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

i have two php file  one input page another results page . input page have checkbox. code looks like this

```
 <form action="" id="frmCalculators" method="post"  name="frmCalculator">
 <input id="chkUFtoLoan-1" name="S"  value="S" type="checkbox" checked /> 

    <button id="Button4" type="submit" onclick="GetPage()"  class="dont-compare shadow-inset  ">
   Calculate Scenarios</button>
```

I have passed check box value next page  php

```
 <?php 

session_start();

$checkbox1 = $_POST["S"];

?>
```

i have tired checked using echo value passed in results php.
 Now i have  question  i have value in results page looks like

**About your Loan :**

```
<label id="FinancedUpfrontMIP"  class="pull-left">Financed Upfront MIP</label>
      <label id="financedmip"  class="pull-right">$<?php echo round($arrFirstBox["upfrontmipamt"],2);?></label>
```

**Buyer close to section:**

```
  <label id="FinancedUpfrontMIP"  class="pull-left">Financed Upfront MIP</label>
          <label id="financedmip"  class="pull-right">$<?php echo round($arrFirstBox["upfrontmipamt"],2);?></label>
```

my question user select check box value display about your loan if user not select  checkbox value  display buyer close to section.. Now display same value both place. if one value one show another value need to show Zero.. please any idea about  it?

Comment: Please read after you write a question and before posting it....your question is misleading and confusing

Comment: how to check post value depends checkbox select its my question